# Can't add attachment to email using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am having a very strange problem with this code. The general purpose is to save user data from a form in Access to a spreadsheet in Excel, and then use an email client to send an email containing the spreadsheet attachment. The code is as follows

```
    Private Sub Send_Email_Click()

Dim MySheetPath As String
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

' Tell it location of actual Excel file
MySheetPath = "\\SERVER\Users\Public\Documents\WORK ORDERS\Blank Work Order.xlsx"

'Open Excel and the workbook
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
Xl.Visible = True
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

'Insert values in the excel sheet starting at specified cell
XlSheet.Range("B6") = Jobnameonform.Value
XlSheet.Range("C7") = Companynameonform.Value
XlSheet.Range("C8") = Employeename.Value
XlSheet.Range("H7") = Jobnumberonform.Value
Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Xl.Quit

'in case something goes wrong
Set Xl = Nothing
Set XlBook = Nothing
Set XlSheet = Nothing

Dim cdomsg
Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "matthewfeeney6@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "REDACTED"
    .Update
End With
' build email parts
With cdomsg
    .To = "matthewfeeney6@gmail.com"
    .From = "matthewfeeney6@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Test email"
    .TextBody = "Did you get the attachment?"
    .AddAttachment "\\SERVER\Users\Public\Documents\WORK ORDERS\Blank Work Order.xlsx"
    .Send
End With
Set cdomsg = Nothing

MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

Without the line ".AddAttachment..." The code works exactly as intended, minus sending the attachment of course. However, with that line, I get a runtime error 91, with the debugger citing the line "Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save" as the problematic code. Also, without the code to modify the excel spreadsheet, the simple email portion does work, attachments included. If anyone can provide insight as to why I am getting this error, that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Retesting the code, it seems to consistently crash at Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save  I thought it worked before, but I must have been mistaken

Comment: Are you telling me that if you add the line `.AddAttachment ""`, it crashes at `Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save` and without it it runs fine?! VBA is a line by line program, its impossible that it crashes BEFORE something that you modify (for instance, adding something at the end wouldn't crash before getting to it...)

Comment: EDIT: I just re-tested the code. I was mistaken. It continually crashes at Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save

Comment: @user3656992 I have a feeling that you are trying to attach the workbook containing the code above to the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (think you) are saving and closing your workbook with:

```
Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

but that's not the workbook you're using and manipulating, which is `XlBook`:

```
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)
```

If you save and close the "real" workbook, `XlBook`:

```
XlBook.Save
XlBook.Close
```

then it should work.

The reason you're getting the error at the `Save` call probably means that the `Xl.ActiveWorkbook` object doesn't exist/is null or something.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3656992: You are welcome. Another pair of eyes can spot these simple things that you may otherwise miss.